# Rainfall Statistics C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an assignment to gather the rainfall for twelve months. I have the code almost done but I keep getting these error messages:

> `'rainfall'` :           `undeclared identifier`
>   `'month'` :                 `undeclared identifier`
>   `'Stats::getAvg'` : `function does not take 0 arguments`
>   `'rainfall'` :           `undeclared identifier`
>   `'month'` :                 `undeclared identifier`
>   `'rainfall'` :           `undeclared identifier`
>   `'month'` :                 `undeclared identifier`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Stats
{
private:
    double value;
    double total;
    double avg;
    double largest;
    double smallest;
    double rainfall[12];
    int NUM_MONTHS;
public:
    void setValue(int, double); // set function

    double getTotal(double[], int); // get functions
    double getAvg(double[], int);
    double getLargest(double[], int);
    double getSmallest(double[], int);

};

void Stats::setValue(int month, double rain)
{
    rainfall[month] = rain;
}

double Stats::getTotal(double array[], int month)
{
    double total = 0.0;

    for (int count = 0; count < month; count++)
        total += rainfall[count];
    return total;
}

double Stats::getLargest(double array[], int month)
{
    double largest = rainfall[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < month; count++)
    {
        if (rainfall[count] > largest)
            largest = rainfall[count];
    }
    return largest;
}

double Stats::getSmallest(double array[], int month)
{
    double smallest = rainfall[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < month; count++)
    {
        if (rainfall[count] < smallest)
            smallest = rainfall[count];
    }
    return smallest;
}

// Function prototype
void rainReport(Stats);

int main()
{
    Stats rainData; // Create an instance of the Stats class
    // to manage rainfall data
    double rain;
    const int NUM_MONTHS = 12; // Number of elements the array can hold
    string months[NUM_MONTHS] = {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    for (int month = 0; month < NUM_MONTHS; month++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #";
        cout << (month + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> rain;
        while (rain < 0)
        {
            cout << "Rainfall must be 0 or more.  Please re-enter: ";
            cin >> rain;
        }
        // Call class setValue function to store this month's rainfall
        // value in the array.
        rainData.setValue(month, rain);
    }

    // Call the rainReport function to produce a rain report.
    // Pass it rainData, which is a Stats object.
    rainReport(rainData);

    return 0;
}

/************************************************************
 *                        rainReport                       *
 * Finds and returns the smallest value stored in the array.*
 ************************************************************/
void rainReport(Stats rainData)
{
    // Display the total rainfall
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;
    cout << "Total   rainfall for the year was ";
    cout << setw(5) << rainData.getTotal(rainfall, month) << " inches." << endl;

    // Display the average rainfall
    cout << "Average rainfall for the year was ";
    cout << setw(5) << rainData.getAvg() << " inches." << endl << endl;

    // Display the largest & smallest amounts of monthly rain.
    cout << "The largest  amount of rainfall was ";
    cout << setw(5) << rainData.getLargest(rainfall, month) << " inches.\n";
    cout << "The smallest amount of rainfall was ";
    cout << setw(5) << rainData.getSmallest(rainfall, month) << " inches.\n";
}
```

Comment: Those error messages have **line numbers** in them. Look at each error message and look at the line that it refers to. Here's a hint: the problems are all in `rainReport`.

Comment: Um, you didn't say what lines the errors are on. We are not psychic. Also, the problem is probably because the identifier is undeclared.

Comment: No, the problem is he's referring to private members of Stat.  To add insult to injury he then doesn't even use the parameter passed in.

Answer (score 2):

`rainReport` is not a member of your class Stats.  So it doesn't know about all the things inside Stats.

```
cout << setw(5) << rainData.getTotal(rainfall, month) << " inches." << endl;
```

so the parameters to getTotal throw the errors.  rainfall isn't even accessible (its private), and you don't use that parameter anyways:

```
double getTotal   (int);  // new definition

double Stats::getTotal (int month)
{
  double total = 0.0;

  for (int count = 0; count < month; count ++)
    total += rainfall[count];  
  return total;
}
```

and call it like `rainData.getTotal( 12)`

Comment: And even without the private function problem, getAvg is declared as taking 2 args (no default values) but when called it is passed none. ...and the function body isn't defined either.

Comment: Ya, I didn't make it pass the first line of trouble.